# What´s the difference between idxmax() and max() inside a groupby pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with data from many players of different teams. What I wanted was to groupby 'team' and only keep the rows with the max value from height.

When I used this code, I just got the 'Team' label and peoples heights:

Code:

```
df.groupby(['team'], sort=True)['height'].max()
```

Output:

team
Argentina         199
Australia         193
Belgium           199 (...)

Then I combined the groupby with loc to get the whole information of the players:

```
fifa.loc[fifa.groupby('team')['height'].idxmax()]
```

This printed the whole rows, but I don´t understand why do I use `idxmax()` and not `max()` at the end of the code.

Can anyone explain me the difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`max()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.max.html) simply returns the maximum value.

[`idmax()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) returns the *index* of the (first occurrence of the) maximum value, not the maximum value itself.

Comment: But in this case both max value and max value index matches. When I try `fifa.loc[fifa.groupby('team')['height'].max()]` it doesn´t work. How can I be sure is printing the full rows with the max 'height' for each team then?

Comment: You're passing the index values returned by `idxmax()` to the `.loc[]` indexing to get the rows that match that index

Comment: So I´m saying to my computer "find the max height value of each group, get the """"row label"""" (index) and use this index to tell the loc which rows I want" ?